# Why is CSS not being loaded onto the "post.html"?

Tags: html, css, flask

I'm working on a 100 days of code: Python Pro Bootcamp project. Here's my Python Flask Application. The issue that I'm having is that when I run the code, all of the pages successfully show CSS except the "post.html" page.

```
import json
from flask import Flask, render_template

URL = "https://api.npoint.io/aa42b8bd75db3f736ba8"
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    response = requests.get(URL)
    data = response.json()
    return render_template('index.html', data=data)


@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')


@app.route('/contact')
def contact():
    return render_template('contact.html')


@app.route('/post/<int:post_id>')
def post(post_id):
    response = requests.get(URL)
    data = response.json()
    post_data = None
    for item in data:
        if item['id'] == post_id:
            post_data = item
            break
    return render_template('post.html', post_data=post_data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='localhost')

# TODO. Stuck on enabling the CSS on the posts.html.
```

Here's the Index html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <title>Clean Blog - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.ico" />
        <!-- Font Awesome icons (free version)-->
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.3.0/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Google fonts-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
        <link href="static/css/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <!-- Javascript-->
        <link href="js/scripts.js" rel="stylesheet"/>

    </head>
<!-- Navigation-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" id="mainNav">
<!--        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; z-index: 9999;" id="mainNav">-->
            <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Start Bootstrap</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    Menu
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto py-4 py-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="{{ url_for('about')}}">About</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="{{ url_for('contact') }}">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

    <body>

        <!-- Page Header-->
        <header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('static/assets/img/home-bg.jpg')">
            <div class="container position-relative px-4 px-lg-5">
                <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                        <div class="site-heading">
                            <h1>Clean Blog</h1>
                            <span class="subheading">A Blog Theme by Start Bootstrap</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- Main Content-->
        <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
            <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                    <!-- Post preview-->
                    {% for item in data %}
                    <div class="post-preview">
                            <a href="{{ url_for('post',post_id=item['id'])}}">
<!--                        <a href="post.html">-->
                            <h2 class="post-title">{{ item['title']}}</h2>
                            <h3 class="post-subtitle">{{ item['subtitle']}}</h3>

                        </a>
                        <p class="post-meta">
                            Posted by
                            <a href="#!">{{ item['author']}}</a>
                            on {{ item['date']}}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <!-- Pager-->
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end mb-4"><a class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase" href="#!">Older Posts →</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        {% include "footer.html" %}
```

Below is my post html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <title>Clean Blog - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.ico" />
        <!-- Font Awesome icons (free version)-->
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.3.0/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Google fonts-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
        <link href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Navigation-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" id="mainNav">
            <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Start Bootstrap</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    Menu
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto py-4 py-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="post.html">Sample Post</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Page Header-->
        <header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('assets/img/post-bg.jpg')">
            <div class="container position-relative px-4 px-lg-5">
                <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                        <div class="post-heading">
                            <h1>{{post_data['title']}}</h1>
                            <h2 class="subheading">{{post_data['subtitle']}}</h2>
                            <span class="meta">
                                Posted by
                                <a href="#!">{{post_data['author']}}</a>
                                on {{post_data['date']}}
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- Post Content-->
        <article class="mb-4">
            <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
                <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                        <p>{{post_data['body']}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
        <!-- Footer-->
        <footer class="border-top">
            <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
                <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                        <ul class="list-inline text-center">
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="#!">
                                    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                        <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                        <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="#!">
                                    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                        <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                        <i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="#!">
                                    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                        <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                        <i class="fab fa-github fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="small text-center text-muted fst-italic">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2023</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
        <!-- Bootstrap core JS-->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Core theme JS-->
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've tried to tinker with the line  `<link href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>` with no success. Does anyone have any idea of how to make CSS load onto the page?

Comment: please show me file structure for your CSS file is in e.g

Comment: projectfilename/Static/css/styles.css.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing Static word while calling css

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <title>Clean Blog - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.ico" />
        <!-- Font Awesome icons (free version)-->
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.3.0/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Google fonts-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
        <link href="static/css/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
```

Comment: Sadly, I tried that but the CSS still does not show up. What else could be the problem?

Comment: i'm quite sure thats the problem what you can do is to copy and paste the head of index file into post.html cause the issue it seems its not recognizing the custom css file you are adding and also tell me is the post.html is in an other folder than index file? cause file structre is very important. send add your whole file structure in your original post too